# How to compile Ruby 1.9.2 with Tk enabled?

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

It is not clear (at least from the docs I read) how to compile ruby 1.9.2 with Tk support.

Could you explain how to compile (on linux, fedora) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Fedora you install packages, you don't need to compile either of them.

1. Use RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2 , e.g.:

   http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

   and

   http://beginrescueend.com/integration/tk/

   in particular do this:

   rvm install 1.9.2 --enable-pthread